# Override email exclusions in Eloqua

Tags: eloqua

Is there any way to override email exclusions in Eloqua eg: from master exclude list or globally unsubscribed?

I need to send an announcement (non-marketing email) and want to ensure it will go to all recipients.

Answer (score 1):

When sending an Email via Campaign Canvas, you can choose to send to the Master Exclude and Unsubscribed under the “Sending Options” tab. Here is a link to the Help Center doc - https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCAA/Help/Campaigns/CampaignCanvasElements/CampaignCanvasElementsAssets.htm#Email